# Linking activity diagram to entities to be accessed

Tags: uml

How do we represent in an Activity Diagram, which entities are to be accessed or updated? Is this is to be done as part of an activity diagram, or to be done separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify which `Classes` are accessed or updated using `Pins` on an `Action` or using an `ActivityParameterNode` on an `Activity`. Those `Pins` look like little squares on the periphery of the `Action`, or rectangles on the diagram frame of an `Activity`, and you connect `OutputPins` to `InputPins` using `ObjectFlows` (which unfortunately look just like the `ControlFlows` that connect `Actions` together). Here's an example from the UML 2.5 spec:

[image]

Now, to answer what I think you are really asking. I think you want to know how to navigate to instances of `Classes` in your model. To do that from an `Activity`, you use a `ReadStructuralFeatureAction` to read properties from the `Class` instance that owns the `Activity` you're specifying. The values flow out of an `OutputPin`. Using `ReadStructuralFeatureActions` you can navigate anywhere your instances allow. (Note that when a `Property` is owned by an `Association` rather than a `Class`, you use one of the `ReadLink*Actions` specializations of `Action`.)

Please see Part 4 of Conrad Bock's excellent series, [UML 2 Activity and Action Models,
Part 4: Object Nodes](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_01/column3/) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

- a dependency (dashed line) or
- an object flow (solid line) to show that an action is interacting with an object or
- an information flow (stereotyped with `<<flow>>`). This way you can specify one or more classes which control the information that is flowing (in the example it is FileTypeObject).

[image]